# Bootstrap/JQuery not working Android Webview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, webview

My code woks fine when opened in browser, but Bootstrap and JavaScript will not load in Android webview.

index.html

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="col-sm-12" id="header">
 <h1>Project Name</h1>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="rowBlank"></div><div class="col-sm-3" id="rowFormControl"><input class="form-control" id="searchTerm" type="text"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-5" id="rowButtons"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="search" type="submit">Wiki</button><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" class="btn btn-    primary btn-md" id="random" target="_blank">????</a></div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-12" id="rowOutput">
  <h3 id="output"></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package my.work.domain.ProjectName;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String url = "file:///android_asset/www/index.html";
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and all the URL from CDN are connectable. And I can `alert` using `jQuery`. So make sure

1. `index.html` located at `app/src/main/assets/www/`
2. Try with below HTML code, it will pop up a message if Jquery loaded successfully

   ```
   <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script src="index.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {
             alert("document ready occurred!");
           });
       </script>
   </head>
   <div class="col-sm-12" id="header">
   <h1>Project Name</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4" id="rowBlank"></div><div class="col-sm-3" id="rowFormControl"><input class="form-control" id="searchTerm" type="text"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-5" id="rowButtons"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="search" type="submit">Wiki</button><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" class="btn btn-    primary btn-md" id="random" target="_blank">????</a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12" id="rowOutput">
   <h3 id="output"></h3>
   </div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: I can't help you without code, but first make sure your Java file look like this question, and the HTML file looks like my answer.